# ASMX post response body missing last character

Tags: c#, web-services, post, https, asmx

I have created `ASMX` web service with method `CheckVat`. If I call this method from `https://my.domain.com/VatValidation.asmx` I get successful `json` response like this:

[image: Successfully called from here]

```
{"Valid":true,"Name":"KD SKLADI, D.O.O.","Address":"DUNAJSKA CESTA 63, 1000 LJUBLJANA","ErrorMessage":"","Date":"27.8.2015 15:17:40"}
```

But when I call web method from `JavaScript` with `jQuery` `$.post` method on URL `https://my.domain.com/VatValidation.asmx/CheckVat` (requesting `json`) fail handler is invoked with following response:

[image: Fail response]

I know that fail handler is invoked because `json` isn't valid. But I don't know why last character is missing.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with response character encoding, is works after setting it to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

I just now encounter the same issue, with some trial and error below lines worked for me.

Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", (serviceOutput.Length+2).ToString());

serviceOutput is the string variable wich contains my Json string.

Let me know if this is helpful.

Thanks,
Bishnu.